Child component failed to update from parent ref
I'm trying to update a chain of components from side class by passing a callback to function with a ref variable update (component with a class to listen to websocket).
After the callback is called, i receive an warning Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "teamInfo". Expected Object, got Undefined and all of child components are failed because of undefined data was passed into them.
I tried to update ref from same component by making a button and calling a function that will do the same thing as a class with callback, but the data is successfully updated.
Minimal code sample to test:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import {HubConnectionBuilder} from "@microsoft/signalr";

enum DecryptoTeam {
  Unknown = 0,
  Red = 1,
  Blue = 2
}

interface DecryptoMatchFake {
  round: number;
  teams: { [key in DecryptoTeam]: TeamFake };
}
interface TeamFake {
  players:               { [key: string]: string };
}

let loading = ref<boolean>(true);
let matchInfo = ref<DecryptoMatchFake | null>(null);
const props = defineProps<{ id: string }>();

const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/api/decryptoMessageHub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

function start() {
  try {
    connection.start().then(() => {
      connection.invoke("JoinMatch", props.id);
      connection.on("StateChanged", (match: DecryptoMatchFake) => {
        matchInfo.value = match;
        loading.value = false;
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    setTimeout(start, 5000);
  }
}

start();
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="loading" class="title">
    Loading match data...
  </div>
  <div v-if="matchInfo" class="content">
    <p class="title">Round #{{matchInfo.round}}</p>
    <div class="split">
      <div class="team">
        <div class="block-center">
          <p v-for="player in matchInfo.teams[DecryptoTeam.Blue].players">{{player}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Full source code is available here.

You can put the relevant minimal code directly in your post with markdown

I wish i could... I'm not aware why this is happening and was not able to reproduce it with a separate minimal code.

@Rincew1nd Reduce the amount of code till the problem is still reproducible, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The question should contain enough information to be understandable if external links become unavailable, this is required by SO rules

Made a minimal sample that reproduce that issue. On a page start subscription to SignalR hub happens. Any 'StateChanged' events will update a matchInfo ref (all updates will always be defined and filled with data), that should lead to DOM update, but in reality it will fails with undefined 'matchInfo.teams[].players' in v-for element. If we inspect 'matchInfo' in any time with a debugger (except the time before the first message, thats why we guard elements with 'v-if' and 'loading'), it will always be defined and contains all data that is needed.

@Rincew1nd It lacks code that causes "Expected Object, got Undefined" error, there's no teamInfo prop. You try to simplify this with v-for="player in matchInfo.teams[DecryptoTeam.Blue].players", correct? "If we inspect 'matchInfo' in any time with a debugger" - how exactly do you debug this? This shouldn't happen any time, just once is enough to cause an error. That you have it means  that at some point matchInfo.teams is defined but there's no "Blue" key. This depends on socket data you receive on your side which only you can see, this is what you need to provide for a reproducible example

@EstusFlask thanks. You lead me to thoughts about wrong data, and indeed it was wrong. There was no errors about wrong types (i though that TS will be more aggressive when checking stuff) so i assumed that types was correct. The problem was in default serialization of dictionary keys in System.Text.Json.

Good you worked this out. TS doesn't check data at runtime, type assertion just tricks it into thinking it's ok. You'd need a validator to catch this kind of problems

Thanks for the information. I will look into it!

In your TeamInfo.vue file you are updating matchInfo onMounted but this lifecycle hook is only called after the template has already compiled (see vue lifecycle hooks).

the onMounted hook can be used to run code after the component has finished the initial rendering and created the DOM nodes

Your components are being passed props which are still null. I would try moving your DecryptoDataService.getMatch(props.id) promise into script setup - that way it gets run during setup rather than after the template is compiled. You'll probably be good to just completely remove the onMounted hook.

"I would try moving your DecryptoDataService.getMatch(props.id)" - do you suggest to use suspense? If not then this is not a solution. Asynchronous side effect in setup is a bad practice that should be avoided, this is incompatible with SSR and gives false impression that this allows to avoid race condition

Thanks. It's a helpful suggestion and i will use it in next revision. To prevent those errors i'm using 'loading' variable and guarded template that relies on 'matchInfo' with v-ifs. But original problem lies in websocket updates of matchInfo ref. For some reason after updates from websocket message 'matchInfo' becomes undefined for template, but with a debugger i could see that ''matchInfo.value' contains all information needed.

I found the issue. It was a matter of a wrong serialization of dictionary keys on a backend side. I fixed it with a custom serializer for a dictionary keys, but haven't thought that SignalR will have the same problem.
Before:
{... teams: {'Blue': {}, 'Red': {}} }

After:
{... teams: {1: {}, 2: {}} }

